# Xpath start scraping after certain class and stop before next class

Tags: xpath

```
<div class='example'>
<h4 style="" class="">Exterior Design</h4>
<p>Paragraph 1 text</p>
<p>Paragraph 2 text</p>
<h4 class="">Interior Design</h4>
<p>Paragraph 3 text</p>
<h4 class="">Accommodation</h4>
<p>Paragraph 4 text</p>
<h4 class="">Leisure & Entertainment</h4>
<p>Paragraph 5 text</p>
<p>Paragraph 6 text</p>
<h4 class="">Amenities</h4>
<p>Paragraph 7 text</p>`enter code here`
</div>
```

I am trying to grab any `p` tag text from this html between each `h4` heading, problem is, some of this text uses 1 `p` tag, some 2 `p` tags, also the information appears in different orders on each page, so sometimes the "Design" text is above "Exterior Design" in the page code. I do know the names of the `h4` classes though. What I am trying to do is have xpath

Find the name of an `h4`, grab all text underneath it, stop at the next `h4` on the page, regardless of what the `h4` text is.

I have lots of variations on this:

```
//h4[starts-with(., 'Accom')][1]/following-sibling::h4[1]/preceding-sibling::p

//h4[starts-with(., 'Accom')]/following-sibling::h4[1]/preceding-sibling::p/text()
```

So in this example, my output should be: "Paragraph 4 text" and nothing else at all. But I keep grabbing all the p tags on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
//h4[contains(., 'Interi')]/following-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::h4[1][contains(., 'Interi')]]
```

Result: "Paragraph 3 text"